# What are the speeds of a bus and bike if they are heading in opposite directions? Unsure on how to go about solving for speed here

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Cities $A$ and $B$ are $70$ miles apart.  A biker leaves City $A$ at the same time that a bus leaves City $B$.  They travel toward each other and meet $84$ minutes after their departure at a point between $A$ and $B$.  The bus arrives at City $A$, stays there for $20$ minutes, and then heads back to City $B$.  The bus meets the biker again $2$ hours and $41$ minutes after their first meeting.  What are the speeds of the bus and the biker?

So far, I’ve created 2 variables $V_{\text{bus}}=$ bus speed and $V_{\text{bike}}=$ bike speed.  Where they meet for the first time, I’ve marked that as distance $C$.  From this I got $1.4 \text{ hrs} = C/{V_{\text{bike}}} = (70–C)/V_{\text{bus}}$.

To describe the time in which the bus begins heading back to City $B$, I did $(70/V_\text{bus})+1/3$ hrs which means the bike has traveled $V_\text{bike}((70/V_\text{bus})+1/3)$ by the time the bus leaves again.  This is all I have so far but I’m still unsure if I’m even heading in the right direction.

If it helps at all, the textbook I’m working out of has the answers as $35$ m/h and $15$ m/h but has no work.

Comment: Presumably they both travel at constant speed. What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @Arthur speed is always a constant because its a proportional function, while as velocity is speed plus a direction. Its a scalar quantity so it has just magnitude not magnitude and direction. $y\x$ not an integration like $ab$

Comment: Please edit the title to be more specific.

Comment: @Barb I know for a fact that when I ride a bike or a bus, neither speed nor velocity are constant. I merely wanted confirmation that we actually make such an assumption in this problem.

Comment: @Kale: You may find the simpler solution just posted useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A = (0,0)$ and $B = (70, 0) $, then the bike position is

$ p(t) = v_1 t $

while the bus position is

$ q(t) = 70 - v_2 t $

The time when they meet the first time is

$ t_1 = \dfrac{70}{v_1 + v_2} = 84 \text{ minutes } = \dfrac{7}{5} \text{ hours } $

Therefore, $v_1 + v_2 = 50 $

The bus reaches the origin at $t_1 = \dfrac{70}{v_2} $ , waits for $\dfrac{1}{3} $ hour, then heads back to $B$, therefore, for $ t \gt t_1 + \dfrac{1}{3} $  we have

$ p(t) = v_1 t $  and $ q(t) = v_2 (t - t_1 - \dfrac{1}{3 } ) $

These two are equal at $t = \dfrac{7}{5} + 2 \dfrac{41}{60} = \dfrac{245}{60} \text{hours} $

Hence,

$ v_1 \left( \dfrac{245}{60} \right) = v_2 ( \dfrac{245}{60} - \dfrac{20}{60} - \dfrac{70}{v_2} ) $

Simplifying,

$ 245 v_1 = 225 v_2 - 4200 $

From above, $v_2 = 50 - v_1$, hence

$ 245 v_1 = 225 (50 - v_1) - 4200 $

$\Rightarrow 470 v_1 = 7050 $

So $v_1 = \dfrac{7050}{470} = 15 \text{ mi / hour } $

From which it follows that $v_2 = 50 - v_1 = 35 \text{ mi / hour } $

Comment: Your ans is correct (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Let the speeds of the biker and bus be $a,b$ mph respectively.

The first equation is easy, $(a+b) = \frac{70}{1.4} = 50\;\; ...\;\;[I]$

The next time they meet is $2h\, 41\, min = 161\, min$ later, but $B$ has traveled $20$ *min* less due to stop, and has still travelled $70$ miles more than $A$

Thus $b(84+161-20)/60 - a(84+161)/60= 70$

or $\frac{225}{60}b - \frac{245}{60}a = 70 ....[II]$

Solving, $a = 12\, mph,\; b = 15\, mph$

---

**NOTE**
This question already has an approved answer which I've upvoted, I made a mess at that time. Having found a simpler solution shorty thereafter, I hesitated to post, but now that it is all done and dusted, I thought a simpler solution would be useful to students appearing in competitive exams.

Comment: So I probably should’ve mentioned this in my post so I’ll update it but the textbook I’m working out of says that the answers are 35 m/h and 15 m/h.  However it just provides answers and not the work so you could be right about faulty figures

Comment: No.  Actually, there is no faulty figures, the answers of $15$ mi/hour and $35$ mi/hour are correct and exact with the given information.

Comment: @trueblueanil Please check my solution.